# Does anyone know how to fix this Hmisc error?

Tags: r, hmisc

Trying to run `Hmisc`, but I'm getting this error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Hmisc’ in loadNamespace(j
>   <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):  there
>   is no package called ‘knitr’

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: `install.packages(knitr)` and then try again

Comment: Well, `install.packages("knitr")` -- you need to pass a character value to `install.packages`.